# Give an example of a function that when composed with itself is a bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question:

Is it possible to have a function  $f: A\to B$  so that $f\circ f$   is a bijection if $A \neq B$??

I was asked to give two examples where the above is true. Both of my examples required that I defined A=B.

For example, Let A=B= $\mathbb{R}$ and define $F:A \to B$ as $f(x)=x$.

then $f[f(x)]=f(x)=x$ $\forall x \in A$

Thanks for any and all help.

EDIT - to clarify, I was asked to give two examples where $f \circ f$ is a bijection. The question places no restrictions on A,B.

Comment: What's $f\circ f$ when $A\neq B$?

Comment: John's point is that the first $f$ results in an element of $B$, but $f$ is defined to act on $ A$.  Note that your were asked to make $f \circ f$ a bijection, not necessarily the identity, though there are many more choices of $f$ that make $f \circ f$ the identity.

Comment: I think it is nonsensical to discuss $f \circ f$ when $A \neq B$ because we have no idea whether or not $f(x) \in B$ is also in B. My thinking is that this is only possible with A=B

Comment: I think the intention is to have $f$ defined on a set $C\supseteq A\cup B$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider te more general situation: if $f\circ g$ is bijective, what can be said of $f$ and $g$? A classic result is:

- If  $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ is injective (one simply shows the contrapositive: if $g$ is *not* injective, $f\circ g$ can't be either).
- If  $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective (also one shows the contrapositive).

There results that if $g=f$ and $\,f\circ f$ is bijective, $f$ is too.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to define $f \circ f$ unless $f: A \to A$. But let's consider $A = 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = 2\mathbb{Z} + 1$ let $f(x) = x + 1$ $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. then you can define $f\circ f$

**note:** $f\circ f(2\mathbb{Z}) = 2\mathbb{Z}$ while $f(2\mathbb{Z})=2\mathbb{Z} +1$

you can consider $f_1: 2 \mathbb{Z} \to 2 \mathbb{Z}+1$ the restriction of $f$ to the set $2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $f_2 : 2 \mathbb{Z} + 1 \to 2 \mathbb{Z}$ the restriction of $f$ to the set $2 \mathbb{Z} + 1$ (note that altough $f_1 \circ f_2: 2 \mathbb{Z} \to 2 \mathbb{Z} $ is bijective it is not true that $f_1\circ f_2 (x) = f \circ f (x)  = x$ indeed the case is $f_1\circ f_2 (x) = f \circ f (x)  = x-2$ )

Hope this is interesting

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$.  Your $A$ would be $\mathbb R\setminus \{-1\}$.  Now you need your $B$ to be surjective.

Observe that 
$$ f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1} = 1 + \frac{2}{x-1}.$$

$\frac{2}{x-1}$ will never be zero so $f(x)$ will never be $1$.  So your $B$ is $\mathbb R\setminus \{1\}$.  This gives us $A\neq B$.

Let $f(a) = f(b)$:
We have

\begin{split} \frac{a-1}{a+1} = \frac{b-1}{b+1} &\Leftrightarrow \frac{a−1}{b+1} = \frac{a+1}{b−1} \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow ab+a−b = ab−a+b \\
&\Leftrightarrow 2a=2b \\
&\Leftrightarrow a=b.
\end{split}

This proves $f$ is injective. Therefore $f$ is bijective.

For $f(f(x))$, any composition of a bijection is still a bijection.

Comment: Wellcome! I have edited your question to fix the formatting. You can click edit to see what I have done (and learn some latexing ^^). For more information please see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Wow John,  thank you!!!  So it's just LaTex?

Comment: Yes, indeed~. ${}{}$